# Trouble cloning repo from TFS2013

Tags: git, git-tfs

I am trying to migrate/convert a single branch from TFS2013 to local git repo, while preserving the change history.

I can execute `git-tfs list-remote-branches http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`, and see the repo I'm after, but when I attempt to execute `git-tfs clone http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Brand%20It/Main/ $/BrandIt/Main`, where `tfsserv` is my TFS server, `Brand It` is the TFS project and `Main` is the branch I'm after, I get the following error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/bellhousem/Desktop/GitTfs-0.27.0/Main/.git/

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Brand It/Main/.
Team Foundation Server Url: http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Brand It/Main/.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
All the logs could be found in the log file: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt
```

As far as I can see [here](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md) or [here](https://hmemcpy.com/2014/06/migrating-from-tfs-to-git-to-visual-studio-online-the-survival-guide/), I think I'm using the right command. Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Dis you provided username and password in the clone command line? I think you must do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified the incorrect Team Foundation Server URL, it should be the collection URL.

It **should not be** "`http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Brand It/Main/`"

Just trying below command:

```
git tfs clone http://tfsserv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/BrandIt/Main
```

Comment: My mistake was that I thought the solution path needed to be included as part of the collection location url.